# Regular Expression to identify a Guid followed by a number

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a Regular Expression that will identify Guid's.

```
string pattern = @"[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}"
```

And I have a Regular Expression that will identify numbers

```
string pattern = "^[0-9]+$"
```

I need to combine these two Regular Expression.
My task is to identify following type of string from a sentence.

```
  Input : id=1 name=4a3779ab-56cc-41b5-ac7c-03bbf673439c-53607.jpg count=53607
  Output : 4a3779ab-56cc-41b5-ac7c-03bbf673439c-53607.jpg 
   or just 4a3779ab-56cc-41b5-ac7c-03bbf673439c-53607
```

Output is a Guid followed by a dash('-') and a number.

How can I get this kind of Regular Expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\b[\dA-F]{8}-[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{12}-\d+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL7dU0/1)

```
string input = "id=1 name=4a3779ab-56cc-41b5-ac7c-03bbf673439c-53607.jpg count=53607";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"\b[\dA-F]{8}-[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{12}-\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string output = null;
if (m.Success)
    output = m.Value;
```

Comment: @Umirov - What if my input will contain multiple Guids? I am assuming that there can be multiple Guid in input but the combination of "Guid-Number" will be only one

Comment: @TBAG Sorry, misinterpreted your question. I updated the answer. It matches `guid-number` pattern.